# Specifying monthly x-axis ticks in Bokeh

Tags: bokeh

I have a Bokeh chart with dates on the x-axis, each one representing a single month:

```py
from datetime import date
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure

data = {
    "months": [date(2019, 5, 1), date(2019, 6, 1), date(2019, 7, 1), date(2019, 8, 1)],
    "dogs": [7, 5, 12, 8],
    "cats": [25, 20, 10, 7],
}

column_data = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

p = figure(
    min_width=500,
    plot_height=300,
    sizing_mode="stretch_width",
    toolbar_location=None,
    tools="",
    x_axis_type="datetime",
)

p.varea_stack(
    ["dogs", "cats"],
    x="months",
    color=["#ff0000", "#00ff00"],
    source=column_data,
)
```

But, when there aren't many x-axis ticks, Bokeh adds "extra" ticks between the month-starting dates:

[image]

I'd like to restrict the number of x-axis ticks, e.g. to only be the 1st of each month. I've tried things like this, which result in *no* x-axis ticks being shown:

```py
import calendar
from bokeh.models.tickers import FixedTicker

p.xaxis.ticker = FixedTicker(
    ticks=[calendar.timegm(d.timetuple()) for d in data["months"]]
)
```

And:

```py
from bokeh.models.tickers import MonthsTicker

p.xaxis.ticker = MonthsTicker(months=[1])
```

From the [ticker documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tickers.html) I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have only configured the `MonthsTicker` with a single month (January) that is off-screen with the data above. The ticker should be configured with all the months you want displayed:

```
p.xaxis.ticker = MonthsTicker(months=list(range(1,13)))
```

[image]

Comment: Ah! So simple, thank you! From the documentation saying "The intervals of months to use" I did not even come close to understanding what it meant.

Comment: Agreed those helpstrings are not the best. If you would like to contribute improvements, the file to make a Pull Request against is here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokeh/models/tickers.py#L177